# upload HTTP error in magento ver 1.7

Tags: magento

I cant upload a photo to the product in magento ver 1.7. I have already tried changing the permission . Tried in different browsers. It works fine when I do it locally but not working when doing it online. And I didn't get the idea about .htaaccess file. What are the changes I have to make in that file and where. Please do help.

Comment: not even a small sized image?

Comment: what image are you asking

Comment: no cant even add small sized image

Comment: magento have a version 7.1 !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check following

1) your application's root directory should not be password protected.

2) Flash player should be installed on your system.

Comment: how to remove the password of the root directory

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem on my Ubuntu 10.04 server. It was caused by this particular setting.

Now I made the following change in this file: `/etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf` (you must have root access to modify it):

```
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
```

Almost on the end after the last row of Fcgi commands and before the `</IfModule>` just add:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    AddHandler    fcgid-script .fcgi
    FcgidConnectTimeout 60
    FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
</IfModule>
```